# Objective-C - EXC_BAD_ACCESS error with ALAsset and XmlWriter

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary, xmlstreamreader

I'm using the `ALAssetLibrary` to retrieve information about the images on the device (IOS Simulator) for the moment.
Now that I have the needed information, I want to write them like an `xml file`. To do this I'm using the `XmlStreamWriter` (https://github.com/skjolber/xswi) simple and easy to use. My problem is that I'm having a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1)` error when I run the application. I know that it is related to the `streamWriter` because if I comment this lines of code the program work perfectly.
Here there is my code (I'm using `ARC`):

```
XMLWriter* xmlWriter = [[XMLWriter alloc]init];
[xmlWriter writeStartDocumentWithEncodingAndVersion:@"UTF-8" version:@"1.0"];
[xmlWriter writeStartElement:@"Photos"]; 
NSMutableArray *list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
if (group) {
   [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
   [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){
       if (asset){
                [xmlWriter writeStartElement:@"Photos"];
                NSString *description = [asset description];
                NSRange first = [description rangeOfString:@"URLs:"];
                NSRange second = [description rangeOfString:@"?id="];
                NSString *path = [description substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(first.location + first.length, second.location - (first.location + first.length))];
                [xmlWriter writeAttribute:@"id" value:path];
                [xmlWriter writeEndElement:@"Photos"];                    
            }
        }];
    }
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error enumerating AssetLibrary groups %@\n", error);
}];
[xmlWriter writeEndElement];
[xmlWriter writeEndDocument];
NSString* xml = [xmlWriter toString];
NSLog(@"XML: %@", xml);
```

Any idea of what can be the problem?

I also have an image with the related error:
[image: Error image]

Thanks

Comment: What is the stack trace for the exception? Any log printed from the exception?

Answer (score 2):

`enumerateGroupsWithTypes` calls the block to process the found information asynchronously. So, you are calling `[xmlWriter writeEndDocument` before you have ever actually written any real content into the writer.

You need to change how you complete the write operation so that it is done inside the block and when `group` is passed as `nil`. Add an `else` block to your existing check and put

```
[xmlWriter writeEndElement];
[xmlWriter writeEndDocument];
NSString* xml = [xmlWriter toString];
NSLog(@"XML: %@", xml);
```

In it (and whatever you subsequently do).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Have you got any suggestion?